# Keeping space before text constant after previous text on the same line

Tags: spacing

My problem is hard to explain without a picture, so here's one.

[image: Here's what I want to do and what it's doing wrong.]

As can be seen from the image, I want to make an environment that prints out the letter Q and the number of the question, a skip and then the question. In this example only Q3 looks like I want it to.

I still haven't found a way to make the first letter of the first word of the question to always line up with the indent of the next lines, does anyone here have a fix?

Here's the code I used to generate the text in the picture, it's a hack-job I know.

```
\newenvironment{que}[1][]{\medskip
\large\noindent
\bfseries
\makebox[mmm][l]{Q\thequestion\enskip}
\hangafter=1 \setlength{\hangindent}{\widthof{mmm}}
\stepcounter{question} }
```

Another issue I have with this code is that I'd like it to automatically add a \medskip at the end, but if I do that for some reason \hangafter doesn't add the indents I want.

Comment: Use a (enumerate-like) list. See e.g. the enumitem package.

Comment: why are you not using a latex list???? the code is adding lots of spurious space characters which is why the space shown in your image between the number and start of text is variable, but without a proper reproducible  test document not a lot can be said, You should just be using `\begin{enumerate}` and `\item` or a custom list definition based on the same internals

Comment: You must surely get a TeX error from `\makebox[mmm][l]{Q}`  `! Missing number, treated as zero.` ? (after an error don't even look at the generated pdf, it is typically nonsense)

Comment: you might be able to get rid of the stretchy space at the beginning of the text on the first line if you just put `%` after the close braces following `\enskip}` in the definition.  (not tested)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newenvironment{que}{%
\large\bfseries
\begin{enumerate}[label=Q\arabic*]}
{\end{enumerate}\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}


\section{zzz}

zz zzz zzz

\begin{que}

\item one two three one two three one two three one two three one two three
\item Apples  one two three one two three one two three one two three one two three
\item Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious  one two three one two three one two three one two three one two three one two three one two three one two three one two three one two three one two three one two three one two three one two three
\item one two three
\item one two three
\item one two three
\end{que}



\end{document}
```